# Jquery Ajax using Date to send variable

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, mysqli

i have the following code.

it doesnt work.

any help would be fantastic.

date.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/
ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(".date").change(function()
{
var id=$(this).val();
var dataString = 'id='+ id;

$.ajax
({
type: "POST",
url: "process.php?process=dselect",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{
$(".data").html(html);
} 
});

});

});
</script>
        </head>

<body>
<form method="get" action="index.php">
<input name="date" type="date" value=""/>
                <p>Select Patroller</p>
                <select name="data" class="data" size="20">
                <option>Select Patroller</option>

                    </select>

<input name="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />                   
</form>
```

process.php

```
case "dselect":

include('dbconnect.php');
if($_POST['id'])
{
$id=$_POST['id'];
$query = "SELECT id, name, reason FROM taken WHERE date = '$id'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$id=$row['id'];
$name=$row['name'];
$reason=$row['reason'];
echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$name.' | '.$reason.'</option>';
}
}
}

break;
```

this does work if i have another select box rather than a input date, but i require it to be a date.

your help would be appreciated.

Comment: you forgot to give class to the <input name="date" type="date" class="date"  value=""/>

Comment: thank you so very much works a treat.

Comment: Glad to know that it works !!!

Comment: can i ask i want to add another element to the change function, how can i add to it but keep the existing one working, so both fire or either fire if that makes sense.

Comment: if you want to add more variables :
then do it like this :
var id=$(this).val();
var var1 = 'value1';
var dataString = 'id='+ id+'&var1='+var1;